# is it possible to create new file directory in any specied path with mkdir()

Tags: php, mkdir, include-path

i am trying to understand mkdir() function in php.I have specied a path for this function where to create the file.But it is creating a new one in the same directory where my php file lies.my code is

```
mkdir("d://movie/new file");
```

but on second reload of my php page it says it exists on the following directory.That means it didn't create in the specied folder.

> Warning: mkdir(): File exists in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\bal.php on
>   line 4

I have checked the manual. mkdir() function doesn't look for  [include_Path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) (at least it is said in the manual).

[image]

My question is

is it possible to create new direrctory in any specified path using this function??

Comment: pretty much the same.If their a better option than mkdir please let me know

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_file_create.asp
mkdir is for creating a directory / folder not for making actual files.

Comment: file_put_contents or fwrite. mkdir makes a directory.

Comment: i want to create new directory?not a text file

Comment: changed the question title ,i think you didn't understand me properly.sorry for that

Comment: mkdir("d://movie/new folder"); didn't create it in d://movie directory :( ,all the files are creating in the root htdocs folder in c://xampp/htdocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use backslashes under Windows or use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

```
mkdir('c:\a\b\c\d', 0775, true);
```

OR

```
mkdir('c:'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'a'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'b'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'c'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'d', 0775, true);
```

Comment: thanks! it worked :) .but why backslashes instead of forward slashes .backslashes succeeded in creating new directory in c://xampp/htdocs folder

Comment: I'm not sure, probably It's using your document root and creating the file on it. But, you must use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant for construct an application that can be executed on other systems like linux.

Please check my answer like accepted if I have helped you.